# decompress GIF with multiple data-blocks

Tags: python, gif, compression

I wrote  python script that takes GIF data like this :

```
['8c', '2d', '99', '87', '2a', '1c', 'dc']
```

and turn it to this:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

first I get all the data in all the blocks and turn it to a stream of bits >> I am not sure about this step .I don’t know if I have to decompress all the blocks at once as one stream or decompress them Individually

```
         for byte in data:
             bit=bin(int(m,16))[2:]
             while len(bit)<8:
                 bit='0'+bit
             c.append(bit[::-1] )
         stream=  ''.join(c)  
         decompress(stream)
```

here is the decompress function

```
def decompress(s,InitialCodeSize):
    index=[]
    table=Initialize(InitialCodeSize)
    codesize = InitialCodeSize + 1
    ClearCode=int(math.pow(2, InitialCodeSize))
    L=int(math.pow(2, codesize))
    code = int(s[:codesize][::-1],2)
    s=s[codesize:]
    c = table[code]

    old = c
    for i in c:
       index.append(i)
    while s !='':
      code = int(s[:codesize][::-1],2)

      s=s[codesize:]

      if code == ClearCode:

           table=Initialize(InitialCodeSize)
           codesize = InitialCodeSize + 1

      if code in  list(xrange(len(table ))):
          c=table[code]
          table.append(old + [c[0]])

      else:

        table.append(old + [old[0]])

        c=  old + [old[0]]

      for i in c:
         index.append(i)
      old=c
      if len(table) == L and codesize< 12:
          codesize=codesize+1

          L=int(math.pow(2, codesize))

    return index
```

everything work just fine when the image has few blocks but when it has more blocks it always return smaller number of pixels
for example if the image 522*200 =104400 pixels it give me only 61806 pixels
I though maybe the GIF format uses RLE encoding

**edit**

maybe I wasn’t clear about my question 
what I want to know
is there any different between decompressing one  block of data in GIF file and decompressing multiple blocks??
do I treat these multiple blocks as one stream of data ??
and also  dose the gif format use some sort of RLE as suggested in this article http://www.professordaybell.com/handouts/GIF-JPEG_Compression.pdf ??

Comment: GIF uses LZW encoding. To reproduce your original data, you'll need to (at least) do LZW decoding.

Comment: How exactly did you turn those 7 hexlified bytes into `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`? More importantly, why? What do those 10 numbers represent?

Comment: Meanwhile, the Wikipedia article on [Graphics Interchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) has a nice overview of the file format, including the different ways you can use multiple image blocks (separate tiles, animation, >256 colors, …). If you need more detail, or a more novice-friendly explanation, the article also has links to everything from the actual specs to a tutorials page.

Comment: these numbers ['8c', '2d', '99', '87', '2a', '1c', 'dc'] are just a small portion of the compressed data . and [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] are the data after the decompression

Comment: You'll first need to read and understand the [GIF specification](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) in order to be able to decode GIF image. It is clear from your question that you have not yet invested that time.